# Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI...)

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone explain to me what *UI* stands for in SaveAsUI? Thank you very much!

I was searching the web but couldn't find any helpful explanation.

Comment: **U**ser **I**nterface

Comment: Official explanation is [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave)